# Test onPress button with Enzyme in React Native gives: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'"

Tags: typescript, react-native, enzyme, ts-jest

I'm trying to test the onPress event inside this screen:

```
const MyScreen = () => {return (<View><Button title="Confirm" onPress={()=>console.log('a')}/> </View>)}
```

Here the test:

`

```
describe("Test", () => {

const enzyme = require('enzyme');

const wrapper = enzyme.shallow(<MyScreen/>);
wrapper.find(Button).prop("onPress")!({} as any);});
```

But I get:

● Test suite failed to run

```
Jest encountered an unexpected token

Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

Details:

/MyProject/src/test/myTest.test.tsx:11
    const wrapper = enzyme.shallow(<MyScreen_1.default />);
                                   ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

  at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1479:14)
```

my test.config.js
is

```
module.exports = {
preset: "ts-jest",
"roots": [
    "<rootDir>/src"
],
"testMatch": [
    "**/__tests__/**/*.+(ts|tsx|js)",
    "**/?(*.)+(spec|test).+(ts|tsx|js)"
],
transform: {
    "^.+\\.(js|ts)$": "ts-jest",
},
testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
"snapshotSerializers": ["enzyme-to-json/serializer"],
"moduleFileExtensions": [
    "ts",
    "tsx",
    "js",
    "jsx",
    "json",
    "node"
], globals: {
    "ts-jest": {
        tsconfig: {
            allowJs: true,
        },
    },

}}
```

Anyone has a clue about what could be wrong?

And if I have more buttons, how could I trigger onPress for the right one?

Comment: Its the end closing `View`  tag. Its spelling is wrong. It should've been `const MyScreen = () => { return ( <View><Button title="Confirm" onPress={() => console.log("a")} /></View> ); };`

Comment: @Kartikey sorry, that was just an error in copying the code, the code I'm trying to test, run on the device without problems